# My mouse buttons are inverted when playing Minecraft on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition, mouse

I've been playing Minecraft on the Xbox One and recently got a keyboard and mouse. The problem is that my mouse buttons seem to be inverted, for example when I go to mine a block it places a block instead, etc.

I've looked up how to fix the issue but I have found nothing. I have confirmed that my mouse is right-handed, which means that the issue isn't that I'm mistaking which mouse button is which.

I have tried to adjust the settings on Minecraft to fix my issue, but it didn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions how I should go about correcting the actions of the buttons on my mouse?

Comment: Have you gone into setting and tried switching these?